# Java Script - JSON in hidden form field

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to send POST with JSON content, which comes from hidden form field?

My form looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" name="form0" action="https://my_url/comment/id?Id=5">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="inputField" value='{"number":5,"content":"aaaa"}'/> 
</form>
```

And I would like to send POST with {"number":5,"content":"aaaa"} as JSON not as string.
If I use:

```
document.forms[i].submit();
```

it is send as a string.

Comment: JSON.parse(whatToSend)

Answer (score 0):

An HTML form can only encode data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain` (the latter is not of any practical use).

Your existing code will encode the JSON within that.

If you want to send an `application/json` encoded form body, then you'll need to use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`.

For example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/path/to/handler");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"number":5,"content":"aaaa"}));
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can do so. But you'd need to decode this on the server side, as it will just be transported as string.

Using jQuery, this would be super easy to accomplish:

```
$.post('https://my_url/comment/id?Id=5', {"number":5,"content":"aaaa"});
```

You could even pass a callback to react to whatever is returned:

```
$.post('https://my_url/comment/id?Id=5', {"number":5,"content":"aaaa"}, function (response){
    // Do something cool here.
});
```

Comment: jQuery will encode that data using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. You've ended up with less JSON than the original code.

Comment: Agree, but you passed the data, which is basically what you wanted to do.